Difference between publish method of PublishManager and Publisher
In my application, the Sitecore publishing service (SPS) is configured. I publish items using c# code, one thing I have observed is when I use PublishManger.Publish(publishOption) method uses the SPS service to publish items.
Whereas when I use Publisher.Publish(publishOptions), does not use the SPS service, but it publishes the item to web db. So in this case does it use Sitecore inbuilt publishing service.
Want to know the difference between these two method call

When using publishing service, Sitecore introduced PublishManager(Sitecore.Publishing.Service.PublishManager) as an abstract provider for publishing. Therefore all implementation done using Sitecore.Publishing.Publisher or Sitecore.Publishing.PublishOptions for publishing, needs to be switched with PublishManager to trigger publishing using Sitecore Publishing Service.
When module for Sitecore publishing service is installed, dependency injection configures the Sitecore.Publishing.Service.PublishManager to replace the default publish manager using the below config.
<!-- 
    SITECORE DEPENDENCY INJECTION SERVICE CONFIGURATION
    
    Configures the Sitecore.Publishing.Service.PublishManager to replace the default publish manager.
-->
<services>
     <configurator type="Sitecore.Publishing.Service.PublishingServiceConfigurator, Sitecore.Publishing.Service" />
</services>

Note: Using the Publisher class still will only publish through the built in publisher i.e. default publishing available OOTB.
Hope this helps!!!

If SPS is not configured then PublisherManager uses Sitecore's inbuilt publishing service, in that case, how does it differ from the Publisher method

@AnekarVishal PublishingManager(Sitecore.Publishing.Service.PublishManager) is introduced inside the Sitecore Publishing service.  It uses separate service(.Net Core Application) to publish items that is much faster than built in publishing. When SPS is installed default publish managers get replaced with publishing service PublishingManager. Hope this helps...

Therefore when SPS is not configured PublishManager and Publisher method will use the same way for publishing.

Publisher is the simplest option when it comes to publishing with Sitecore. It starts the backend Sitecore job for publishing without checking if Sitecore Publish Service is enabled or not.
PublishManager uses manager which is registered with Sitecore dependency injection. When you install Sitecore Publish Service, PublishingServiceConfigurator class replaces in Sitecore DI default Sitecore implementation of PublishManager with Sitecore.Publishing.Service.PublishManager instance. That's why when you call PublishManger.Publish method, it gets the instance which uses Sitecore Publish Service to execute publishing.

If SPS is not configured then PublisherManager uses Sitecore's inbuilt publishing service, in that case, how does it differ from the Publisher method?

Both Publisher and PublishManager are used for publishing content in Sitecore, but they differ in their implementation and behavior. Here are the key differences in theory.
Publisher: It offers a simpler approach, directly initiating the built-in publishing engine. It doesn't check if the Sitecore Publishing Service (SPS) is enabled and always uses the built-in publishing. Also it offers limited control over the publishing process.
PublishManager: It provides a more flexible and recommended approach, leveraging dependency injection to determine the publishing mechanism. If SPS is enabled and configured, it leverages its potentially faster publishing capabilities and if it's disabled, it seamlessly falls back to the built-in engine, ensuring compatibility. It provides more flexibility and potential for customization through dependency injection.
Hope it will give you some context.
